# How to put a text input in a td

Tags: html, input

```html
<tr>
  <td width="40%">
    <?php echo $producto['NOMBRE'] ?>
  </td>
  <td width="15%">**<input type="text" name="telnum" value="123456" readonly="readonly"></input>
  </td>****
  <td width="20%" class="Text-center">
    <?php echo $producto['PRECIO'] ?>
  </td>
  <td width="20%" class="Text-center">
    <?php echo number_format($producto['PRECIO']*$producto['CANTIDAD'],2);  ?>
  </td>
  <td width="5%">
    <form action="" method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo openssl_encrypt($producto['ID'],COD,KEY); ?>">
      <button class="btn btn-danger" type="submit" name="btnAccion" value="Eliminar">Eliminar</button>
    </form>

  </td>
</tr>
```

In the part where the td is shown the problem can be seen, I just want to know how to put an input there.
I just want to add a text input there so the quantity of the product could be altered.

Comment: `<input>` doesn't need a closing `</input>`. However, what problem are you facing?

Comment: You want the input telnum will be submit in the form data, right? Are you using jquery? You can use plain JS to handle this but it will be longer a litter bit

Comment: can you help me with that?

Comment: Why do you have it as `readonly`? Without getting into javascript, you can wrap the whole table in the `<form></form>`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the input type to tel and remove read only from the line and see if that helps you solve this problem.  I agree with GetSet, put the table within the form element as well.